# EpiServer simple address short URL without www doesn't work

Tags: episerver, episerver-7

I have been setting simple address in EpiServer 7.5.

I've set a page simple address to banana

However when I enter the URL in the address bar:

website.co.uk/banana (without wwww) doesn't work, just goes to www.website.co.uk
www.website.co.uk/banana works fine

What do I need to do? Change a file in the server or?

Comment: Do other URL:s work without "www", or do all URLs redirect to "www.website.co.uk"?

Comment: All other URL work fine. just the simple addresses when typed in without www. redirect to homepage

Answer (score 1):

Make sure both domains (or wildcard) are properly mapped in "Manage Websites" in admin mode.